# Radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\cos(n)z^n$

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

I already found the radius of convergence for the power series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\cos(n)z^n$ to be $R=1$. It is really messy and uses the squeeze theorem and the Cauchy–Hadamard theorem. Has anyone a nice and short proof for my problem? Is there maybe another way without the theorems I used?

Comment: Since $|\cos n|\le1$ it should be obvious that $R\ge1$. To show $R\le1$ is suffices to show, for example, that $|\cos n|\ge1/2$ for infinitely many $n$ (which implies the sequence $|\cos n||z|^n\not\to0$ if $|z|\gt1$).

Comment: I doubt greatly that there's anything simpler and shorter than Cauchy-Hadamard + a simple use of the squeeze theorem in this case.

Comment: Hint: that's the real part of $\displaystyle\sum^\infty_{n=0}\left(e^iz\right)^n$, and $|e^i|=1$.

Comment: @ProfessorVector, but it's only the real part of that sum if $z$ itself is real, right?

Comment: @Barry Cipra That's correct. Otherwise, you'd have to write $\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac12\left[\left(e^iz\right)^n+\left(e^{-i}z\right)^n\right]$, and (surprise!) $|e^{-i}|=1$ as well.

Comment: @professor it can happen that the sum of two power series has higher convergence radius than either so the argument above needs works;

Comment: @Conrad Why, yes, that's the nature of hints: some own effort is still necessary. Do you really want me to give full solutions of homework/exercises in a mere comment?

Comment: @professor not to argue but I think that going your route is not immediate and ultimately complicates the issue as opposed to the direct easy solution suggested  above by others

Comment: @Conrad Wise decision not to argue, as there is no "direct easy" solution suggested by others. If $z$ is complex, $|\cos n|\ge1/2$ or not is irrelevant, for instance.

Comment: @ProfessorVector: Thank you for the hint. This was pretty much what I tried at first. I soon gave up on it and feel like it would take more work than the proof I have right now.
Also this is not a homework/exercises. I am preparing for an exam and read my old solution to it. I just thought I might remember it better for future purpose if I had a nicer solution to it.

Comment: @professor what one needs to prove is that $|a_n|$ - in this case $|\cos n|$ doesn't decay exponentially so if one proves that it has a non zero limit point (eg $|\cos n_k| \ge a>0, n_k \to \infty$) we are good; if we take a sequence of integers like $10^{n!}$ and construct an irrational $x$ for which $|x-1/10^{n!}| \le 1/10^{2n!}$ (eg scattering $1$'s with tons of zeroes after, taking $a_n=\sin (2\pi10^{n!}x)$ the series $\sum a_nz^n$ is entire while the series one writes per your suggestion as a sum/difference with $e^{\pm 2\pi i10^{n!}x}$ instead have radius of convergence $1$

Comment: @ProfessorVector, how is $|\cos n|\ge1/2$ (for infinitely many $n$) irrelevant for complex $z$? It shows that $|\cos(n)z^n|\not\to0$ when $|z|\gt1$, which is all you need for divergence.

Comment: $R>1$ means the series must converge for $z=1$ which implies $\cos(n)\to 0$ contradiction!